# Rule-based matcher of entities with spacy

Tags: python, information-extraction, spacy

I want to use the python library spacy for matching tokens in a text (adding a labels as a semantic reference). Then, I want to use the matches to extract relations between the tokens. My first was to make use of the `matcher.add` and `matcher.add_pattern` of spacy. The `matcher.add` is working fine and I can find tokens, my code until now:

```
import spacy


nlp = spacy.load('en')

def merge_phrases(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    if i != len(matches)-1:
        return None
    spans = [(ent_id, label, doc[start : end]) for ent_id, label, start, end in matches]
    for ent_id, label, span in spans:
        span.merge('NNP' if label else span.root.tag_, span.text, nlp.vocab.strings[label])



matcher = spacy.matcher.Matcher(nlp.vocab)



matcher.add(entity_key='1', label='FINANCE', attrs={}, specs=[[{spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'financial'}, {spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'instrument'}]], on_match=merge_phrases)
matcher.add(entity_key='2', label='BUYER', attrs={}, specs=[[{spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'acquirer'}]], on_match=merge_phrases)
matcher.add(entity_key='3', label='CODE', attrs={}, specs=[[{spacy.attrs.ORTH: 'Code'}]], on_match=merge_phrases)
```

this works fine and it outputs pretty nice results:

```
doc = nlp(u'Code used to identify the acquirer of the financial instrument.')

# Output
['Code|CODE', 'used|', 'to|', 'identify|', 'the|', 'acquirer|BUYER', 'of|', 'the|', 'financial instrument|FINANCE', '.|']
```

My question is, How can I use the `matcher.add_patern` to match relations between the tokens, something like

```
matcher.add_pattern("IS_OF", [{BUYER}, {'of'}, {FINANCE}])
```

for the output in:

```
doc = nlp(u'Code used to identify the acquirer of the financial instrument.')

# Output
[acquirer of financial instrument]
```

I have tried in different ways to make this works but is obviously not, I guess there is something wrong with my understanding of `matcher.add_pattern`.

1. Can some please put me in the right direction how to do this with
   spacy?
2. Is it possible to add regex here to find patterns, how?
3. How can I add more than one token with the same label, or somehow create
   a list of tokens for the same label, eg. "FINANCE"?

I will appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matcher would identify the tokens, but to find relations between them you will have to do dependency parsing.
Here is [visual example from spacy](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Code%20used%20to%20identify%20the%20acquirer%20of%20the%20financial%20instrument.&model=en&cpu=1&cph=1) :

[image]

You can then traverse the tree to find relations between the tokens.
https://spacy.io/docs/usage/dependency-parse#navigating

The dep (enum) and dep_ (verbose name) attribute of each token would give you the relationships with its child

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helps a lot. I am wondering if it would be more convenient to train the named entitiy model to find find new related entities in my source and then find relation between the entities. There is some documentation about this using NLTK, but how would you approach this with spacy, i mean the relation extraction part?

Comment: Could you provide an example with the dependency parsing, is this compatible with the spacy-matcher, or am I getting the wrong idea here?

Comment: @El_Patrón The link provided in the answer has examples, yes it would be compatible with spacy-mathcher as dependency parse results are attributes of spacy tokens themselves present as dep and dep_